# EventBus da PrimePush não funciona e dará os erros

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, aplicação-web

Estou iniciado a aprender em prática com PrimeFaces a dar PUSH. Segue no link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml

Implementei os códigos a seguindo esse link que postei em cima, usando o servidor web Tomcat, configurei no Maven são PrimeFaces na versão é 5.2 e atmosphere na versão 2.3.0. Executei esse aplicativo, apareceu mensagem de erro veja:

```
30-May-2015 19:52:09.404 1100 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] null.null JSF1073: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException obtido durante o processamento de RENDER_RESPONSE 6: UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Não é possível criar instância para·a classe: com.jsnpereira.primepushchat.ChatView.
30-May-2015 19:52:09.404 1100 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] null.null Não é possível criar instância para·a classe: com.jsnpereira.primepushchat.ChatView.
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Não é possível criar instância para·a classe: com.jsnpereira.primepushchat.ChatView.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:457)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:77)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeContent(FieldsetRenderer.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeMarkup(FieldsetRenderer.java:76)
    at org.primefaces.component.fieldset.FieldsetRenderer.encodeEnd(FieldsetRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jsnpereira.primepushchat.ChatView.<init>(ChatView.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 52 more
```

Esse caso problemas que acontece esse código é:

```
private final EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
```

Como resolver o problema?

Comment: Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException` Provavelmente este trecho `EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();` não está retornando uma instância de um objeto esperado para `private final EventBus eventBus`

Answer (score 1):

Estava com o mesmo problema, o eventBus ficava null, adiciona na lib o javax-inject.jar. Pra mim resolveu.